# How to map elements in XML files to columns in SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have multiple XML files whose data needs to be stored in one table in database. All the files should be mapped to one table.

But the elements names in XML files are different from the column names in the table. How to map the XML elements(from different files) to columns in the SQL table? How to perform this mapping and store the data in required columns? What is the optimal way of doing this task in C# when you have many XML files?

Also to note that every XML file will have different element names and format.

Comment: There isn't a single correct answer.  We need to see the xml and the tables in the database.

Comment: @jdweng table is just one but the files are multiple. What could be the best approach in this?

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Could you provide table schema? Is XML structure by any chance even loosely normalized? By that i mean is it at least any element in-structure order applied?

Comment: @Rusmirnator table will have employee related data in it. and the xml files will also contain employee related data but tag names in those files will be different from column names

Comment: SQLServer is the nodes fct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16 (XML-tables)

Comment: And the reversed pro is

Comment: Using FOR XML RAW/... etc. clauses

Comment: You can use XSLT to transform different XML to same-ish looking XML, and then write a single import for that. But XSLT can be a pain it itself. I'd probably roll up my sleeves and do some hardcode development for each XML format with standard tsql constructs like xml.nodes and xml.value

Comment: Do all of these XML files actually have a flat enough element structure that they can be successfully recorded into a single table? Usually there's a hierarchy to XML elements such that they'll need to get shredded into multiple tables in master-detail style relationships.

Comment: XML parser value

Comment: @hardcoredeveloper I'm sorry for my gibberish in my previous comment, i was thinking about 2 different things at once and mixed them before realising. What i meant was, we know the table is static, and elements have different tags, but are they at least ordered in the same way? E.g. [file1.xml] 
<data>
    <1>Marco</1>
    <2>Polo</2>
    <3>2023.02.17</3>
</data>,
[file2.xml] 
<datum>
    <a>John</a>
    <b>Doe</b>
    <s>2023.02.13</s>
</datum>.